# Are there URL encode conversion websites

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, web

Over the past few weeks i have been dealing with a lot of web authentication processes which can be a pain. Are there some online url encode-decoding conversion websites?

This can be helpful for services that provide API playgrounds for easy understanding of authentication process.

Comment: There are plenty of questions that talk about encoding urls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms to test the auth request and encode url, I would like to recommend a Chrome extension, [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/).

In Postman, parameters you enter in the URL bar or in the key/value editor will not automatically be URL-encoded. Right click on a piece of selected text, and click `EncodeURIComponent` to manually encode the parameter value.

[image]

You can individually add `key/value` pairs and Postman will combine everything together. If your URL already has parameters - for example, if you are pasting a URL from some other source, Postman will split the URL into pairs automatically.

Comment: thanks , that works just fine .

Comment: I already knew that , but it happens alot when your working late   : )